# How to get all Users using a Plugin in Redmine/Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm coding a Plugin for Redmine in Ruby on Rails atm. 
I need to get all "Users" to link them to a "Skill". So I need 
all users to make a relationship to my skills. As it is a plugin, I don't want to write in the
main users model in Redmine. So, I kinda want to extend or something the original user model.
Anyone has a clue how I can solve this?

Comment: Can't you just do `User.all` inside the plugin ? Or are you talking about creating a method in the User class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add logic to an already existing class (like adding new methods, relationships, validations, etc..), you can do it with Ruby `Module#class_eval`:

```
User.class_eval do
  # Inside this block we add the new logic that we want to add to the User class

  def new_method
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To patch models in Redmine I used to use this approach:

```
# plugins/your_plugin_name/lib/your_plugin_name/user_path.rb
module YourPluginName
  module UserPatch
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      has_many :skills
    end

    def some_new_method 
    end
  end
end

User.include YourPluginName::UserPatch
```